# Track console error from wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Native Wordpress Theme on my website and I'm having this weird GET request error in my console.. 
I believe it's something I set up from visual composer (something related to a pattern) but I can't figure how to track this error.
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to track this?

Comment: did you check jquery conflictions with the others.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question with the text of the error, instead of pasting a screenshot. This makes it easier to find for people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the following error GET ... dfd_vc_background/patterns/transperant 404 (Not Found):

*First of all, the word "transperant" is misspelled, "a" and "e" are reversed, should be "transparent".*

I went a bit deeper on this error and this is what the **DFDevelopment team answered:**

> This error can be caused if locale is not setted properly on your
>   server. There are two things you can do to get this sorted: you can
>   get in touch with your hoster and ask to check it for you or you can
>   get in touch with us via **dynamicframeworks@gmail.com** and we’ll edit
>   pattern file names to make them compatible with your locale settings.

*Source: https://themeforest.net/item/ronneby-highperformance-wordpress-theme/11776839/comments?page=300*

To conclude, your answer seems **really specialized** to your case but still **worth a try** to people who are looking for an answer:

> @Ovidiu G: *if you set the background for a row and you set a
>   transparent pattern it will throw that error because there was a typo
>   made by developers.*

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after all.. There was a problem with the Native Theme. For anyone wondering, if you set the background for a row and you set a transparent pattern it will throw that error because there was a typo made by developers.